# How to mock "window.screen.orientation.lock" function using Jest?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, cordova, jestjs

We are using one of the cordova plugins to lock in orientation of our hybrid app. In AppComponent, we have a code that locks down screen orientation. For this purpose, we are using **window.screen.orientation.lock** function. How can I mock the above function using Jest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `Jest` provides a browser-like environment using `jsdom`.

[This](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/d6f8a97b5fb7709d6ad0215c1ae95fd4cab58489/lib/jsdom/living/window/Screen-impl.js) is what `jsdom` implements for `window.screen`.

`orientation` is not implemented by `jsdom`, but it can be added to the `window.screen` provided by `jsdom` during your tests:

code.js

```
export const func = () => {
  window.screen.orientation.lock();
}
```

code.test.js

```
import { func } from './code';

test('func', () => {
  const lock = jest.fn();
  window.screen.orientation = { lock };  // <= add orientation mock to window.screen

  func();

  expect(lock).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```